# Закрывается Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

При работе в AS и попытке отредактировать файлы layout (xml) Android Studio закрывается. Прикрепляю видео. Что это может быть? Гугл обрыл, режимы совместимости проверил, переустанавливал. Пробовал разные SDK.
[YOUTUBE](https://youtu.be/BTkbK90LLF8)

Comment: А какие характеристики у компа? Может просто не тянет?

Comment: Все тянет. Видимо версия ставилась багнутая. Заходя на сайт мне предлогало скачать версию 2020.3.1 for Windows 64-bit (914 MiB), а я потыкал по сайту и нашел  Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 и все стало хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Видимо версия ставилась багнутая. Заходя на сайт мне предлогало скачать версию 2020.3.1 for Windows 64-bit (914 MiB), а я потыкал по сайту и нашел  Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 и все стало хорошо